# Customize ADO.NET Data Service Exception

Tags: ado.net, exception, wcf-data-services

Is it possible to have a DataServiceException pass along a list of errors to consumers?

Rather than just receive the standard Message, Stacktrace information I would also like to have a list of errors when various validations fail on a model.

I tried to set the DataServiceException's inner exception to FaultException.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyTypeWithExtraInfo
{
   [DataMember]
   public List<MyErrorInfo> MyErrors { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyErrorInfo
{
   [DataMember]
   string PropertyId { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

Clientside I do get the DataServiceException but the operation's message only has the FaultException Reason and Type (ToString'ed) it does not have the DataMembers that I have specified in MyTypeWithExtraInfo.

Answer (score 1):

For a single exception, you can catch the actual exception and rethrow:

```
throw new System.ServiceMode.FaultException("Custom Error Message");
```

However, if you need to handle **multiple exceptions**, consider using the [Task Parallel Library Extensions for .NET](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=348F73FD-593D-4B3C-B055-694C50D2B0F3&displaylang=en).  This will allow you to collect all of the thrown exceptions and place them into a single `AggregateException` object.  This library is slated to become part of the .NET 4.0 framework.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have stated that I am trying to use a typed FaultException<T> where I have another object that contains additional information about the error.  That object is marked as a DataContract and its DataMembers are not being serialized and sent to the client.

I have tried what you stated and on the client side all I get is the FaultException Message and Type but not the extra information I would like to pass over.

Comment: I'm looking to perform validation over an entire model during a save. I want to gather all of the validations that fail (not send back one at a time) and then pass all of the errors back together at once. Using something like an object with a list of a bunch of errors.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for the info although this is not a multi processor/hardware issue.  I updated the original question with some example code.